# Definition of a function in an exercise of Guilleman & Pollack's Differential Topology

Tags: real-analysis

Problem 18, part (b), page7:

> Given that$$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> \exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{x^2} \right); & x > 0\\
> 0; & x \leqslant 0
> \end{cases}.
> $$ 
>   Show that $g(x)=f(x-a)f(x-b)$ is a smooth function positive on $(a,b)$ and $0$ elsewhere. (Here $a <b$) Then $$h(x)=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{\infty} ^{x} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}$$
>   is a smooth function satisfying$$
> h(x)=\begin{cases}
> 0; & x<a\\
> 1; & x>b
> \end{cases},
> $$
>   and $0 < h(x) < 1$ for $x \in (a,b)$.

---

I am a bit confused about the definition of function $g$ in the text. Could someone please clarify the definition of $g$ for me?

Comment: Can you explain what is not clear for you?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it should be $g(x)=f(x-a)f(b-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

It probably should be $g(x)=f(x-a)f(b-x)$.

It's just composition of functions: for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ one has
$$f(x-a) = \begin{cases} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}\right), & x-a>0 \\ 0, & x-a\leq0 \end{cases}$$